# Finding the Src Property of a Generic Item

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a simple function to show an image in a gallery, when the user clicks on a thumbnail:

```
function changeImage(s) {
    document.getElementById("img").src=s;
    }
```

Now, at the moment this means that the thumbnail looks something like this:

```
<img 
    src="../images/image.png"
    width="50" 
    height="100" 
    onclick='changeImage("../images/image.png");'
    />
```

With another image called 'img' which is changed.

This is fine, but means having to enter the location twice - which also gets messier when using the same sort of function to change the alt property as well.

So what I want is something like this:

```
function changeImage() {
    var s = [src of thumbnail]
    document.getElementById("img").src=s;
    }
```

Clearly I could name the thumbnail, but then that would require making a new code for each thumbnail - so I'm looking for a generic operator for the src property of the-thing-which has-been-clicked-upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this` in onclick to reference the image:

```
<img 
    src="../images/image.png"
    width="50" 
    height="100" 
    onclick='changeImage(this.src);'
    />
```

Comment: Perfect; exactly what I was looking for -I was just looking at the wrong end!